# What programs are available to measure a PC's boot/start time?

Tags: performance, boot

What programs are available to measure a PC's boot/start time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What operating system are you using?

**Windows XP/2003/Vista/2008/7 (32 or 64 bit):**

[BootRacer](http://www.greatis.com/bootracer/index.html)

> BootRacer allows you to check your Windows boot speed.
>   Race your Windows boot using BootRacer and check your boot rating.
>   If your computer boot time less than one minute you will get Excellent rating!

[image]

[CrystalMark](http://crystalmark.info/?lang=en)

[image]

[image]

**Windows: XP/2000/2003/Vista/2008/XP (32 bit):**

[CrystalMark](http://crystalmark.info/?lang=en)

> Tests all aspects of the system and shows the user  an overall Mark or Score for comparison.

Comment: Combination of multiple Windows OSes

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cell phone, use it. Most cell phones come with a stop watch tool. BTW - here are some results for me:

This is with extremely minimal programs running at startup:
Windows XP (work) --> 2:37 at its fastest
Windows Vista (Home laptop) --> 4:07 at its fastest
Ubuntu (Home desktop) --> 42 seconds

Comment: How the hell is your laptop taking 4 minutes to start up? I'm at 35 seconds now, but it used to be 28. I'm slipping :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: http://bootracer.software.informer.com/

For Windows 7: [Win7zilla](http://www.win7zilla.com/)

Answer (score 0):

**Boot-up Time**

This procedure is fairly simple. Just download it at PlanetSoft ([BootTimer](http://www.planetsoft.org/utils/BootTimer.exe)) and double click on the executable file. On the next restart cycle, the timer will start counting from the time it boots up till the OS loading and display it correctly on the pop up window.

The tiny software utility has the capability to measure the boot time starting from the bootloader until the handling get passed to the OS to move on with proper applications loading. It only consumes around 130kB, which is quite suitable to be used for any Windows PC. Only one drawback, it is said not to work for Linux or other fastboot OSs that takes less than 5 seconds for total boot up time to OS.

Currently it is only compatible with Windows OS such as NT and XP. And for me, it works in Vista as well.

Comment: The link you provided goes to a 404 Not Found - URL: http://www.planetsoft.org/utils/BootTimer.exe

Answer (score 0):

A stopwatch and a fast finger. The advantage here is there's no software to install, it's cross platform (It can measure everything from Chrome OS to Windows 95 without any alterations), and requires little setup to perform.

But seriously, all a program would give you is a few numbers after the decimal point more accuracy - is that really important? :)

Comment: Where can I get a cheap stopwatch? (j/k)

Comment: You could use an existing clock or watch, providing it has a second hand, you'll just need to count in your head :P